# Why is count(*) slow, when explain knows the answer?

Tags: mysql, count, explain

This query: `select count(*) from planner_event` takes a very long time to run - so long, I gave up and killed it before it finished. However, when I run `explain select count(*) from planner_event`, I can see a column in the output with the number of rows (14m).

How come explain can get the number of rows instantly, but count(*) takes a long time to run?

Comment: COUNT(*) without a WHERE cause will cause a table scan on the InnoDB engine.. MyISAM can delivery the count directly because the COUNT is keept in de header file off the table.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Explain is using previously gathered statistics (used by the query optimizer). Doing a `select count(*)` reads EVERY data block.

Here's a cheap way to get an **estimated** row count:

```
SELECT table_rows
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name='planner_event';
```

Even if you did `select count(id)`, it might still take a very long time, unless you have a secondary index on `id` (also assuming `id` is a PRIMARY KEY). Because all data (including Row Data) is stored in B-Tree indexes, performing a `select count(PK_COLUMN)` is still a considerable amount of IO (needs to reads all data pages).  If you have a secondary index on the PK field, it will be able to perform less IO to perform a count.

Comment: I_S.TABLES gives you the same _estimate_ that `EXPLAIN` gives you.

Comment: The query is missing `AND TABLE_SCHEMA='my_database'`, otherwise you will get multiple results back if you have the a table with the same name in another database.

Comment: Incidentally, MySQL should implement [**counted** B-tree indexing to deal with this](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/cbtree.html). Although I guess that would be tricky given @RickJames ' point below about miscounting due to non-committed operations.

Comment: @ijoseph - The stats come from "random probes" into the BTree.  This is faster, but less accurate, than reading the next-to-bottom nodes entirely.  MySQL developers made choices and tradeoffs.

Answer (score 5):

Explain gets the number from some "statistics" that are used to estimate things for the Optimizer.  That number can be far from correct -- I sometimes see it being more than a factor of 2 (higher or lower) than the exact value.

Performing the `COUNT(*)` on an InnoDB table must scan the table to avoid miscounting records that are busy being inserted/deleted by other connections but not yet "committed".  Actually, it is good enough to do a full scan on some index, not necessarily the whole table (which contains the `PRIMARY KEY`).

How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  It might help if that were about 70% of RAM.